# A minha atitude foi correta

Tags: suporte

Vocês podem ver pelas edições das minhas respostas, que na minha primeira edição eu tinha elaborado uma resposta que não resolvia de fato o problema,  na segunda edição inclui o que o colega mencionou nos comentários por que achei que complementaria a resposta, e que de fato estava errado (com uma observação indicando que aquela ediçao se deu pelos comentários), mas na terceira e edição percebi que a minha resposta estava incorreta e apenas a resposta do comentário já era o bastante para sanar a dúvida, então fiz a correção necessária e mantive a minha resposta, mas que na verdade não é de fato minha, o que fiz foi errado no sentido de me "apropriar" do conteúdo dos comentários, ou até mesmo não de se "apropriar" mas é contra alguma regra do SOpt.

Nessa pergunta: [Erro em programa de imposto de renda em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373298/erro-em-programa-de-imposto-de-renda-em-c)

Comment: Se o comentário era o suficiente para resolver então devia ser uma resposta. Se o colega não o quis colocar como resposta então acho que no final a sua resposta com o mesmo conteúdo é algo mais positivo para a comunidade.

Comment: Entendo, então seria melhor manter a resposta lá, é que eu pensei em remove-la, é que geralmente quando tem um comentário evito responder.

Comment: Você pode e deve colocar a resposta. Quando o fizer mencione o nome do utilizador que deu a resposta. Essa é a parte mais importante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considero ok, precisamos de respostas, o ideal era a pessoa ter respondido, mas só o que a pessoa disse de fato era só pra comentar. Fica um jeito meio suspeito de apropriação (mesmo não sendo), mas no fim a comunidade ganhou com sua resposta e isto é o mais importante. Regra não tem, alguns podem não gostar, mas não está errado não. Por exemplo, eu me apropriei do comentário do Isac pra responder aqui já que a pergunta precisa de uma resposta :P :D Pelo menos agora tem algo mais "oficial" sobre o assunto (só deixando claro que apesar de ser moderador esta é só minha opinião pessoal baseada na minha experiência, só posso afirmar que não é contra as regras, não sobre o gosto das pessoas).

Comment: A ironia! Haha :D. Mas não respondi para dar abertura a alguém que está dentro das regras e dos procedimentos desejados no SOpt poder falar e dizer o que deve ser feito. Apenas disse o que na minha opinião faz sentido.